# Passing variables using php and html anf into functions

Tags: php, html

I have used post in my code which main use is taking source and destination from user on one page and then pass it to another php page. I have use post in form for this. I have got the expected variables in the next php file.
My problem is that how can I pass this variable to the function defined in html so that the source and destination are the arguments and the function ruuns on this values.

Thanks in advance.I am new for this forum. So sorry for this type of question format.

Now the selected outputs of from and to in code1 must be given inputs for calculateroute function. Both are .php files.

Comment: Try to add some code to your questio. It will be easier for us if we can see what you already did. and comment it to to tell us where do you want things, why you put things at some place etc...

Comment: share your code

Comment: sorry for that i will try to add in few minutes

Comment: In using echo I am able to print both strings but not able to call that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Code 2 file you are getting $from & $to, now change the script function to

```
$("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculateRoute("<?php echo $from; ?>", "<?php echo $to; ?>");
});
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: This code will produce error is javascript because it'll try to parse your php tags and couldn't understand them, instead the php part must be wrapped in quotes. Try testing your code before posting it for solution.

Comment: @jayaparwani you didnt use post anywhere for the varaibles to get it from the before page. So it would result in error

Comment: @SaiKrishna i guess you have written the code <?php
        $from=$_POST['from'];
        $to=$_POST['to'];
        echo $from;
        echo $to;
    ?> So you are initialising $from & $to variables here so no need to use super global variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

in your `code 2` file php variable directly no use in javascript so you need to following structure to use php variable

```
calculateRoute(<?php echo json_encode($from); ?>, <?php echo json_encode($to); ?>)
```

i think this helpfull

Comment: So is there a need to take the variables using the post in the <?php ?> code or shall I delete that part

Comment: you have to need that code because its assign a value to that variable otherwise that variable not have a value

Comment: I have tried that and now as same as before it is printing the to and from but not taking it as inputs to that function. Also I cant get map on the site. Can you see if there is any other problem.

Comment: comment on `// $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
       //});` to your code

Comment: only write  `event.preventDefault();
          calculateRoute(<?php echo json_encode($from); ?>, <?php echo json_encode($to); ?>);`

Comment: it is not drawing the basic map itself. It is not going into the function that is given. I commented the part you said and wrote the other two lines.Still it is not accessing that code

Comment: you can share your second page code which will map and from to data

Comment: how can i add the code again it is not allowing me here

Comment: thank you very much it has solved my problem.I just had few other small errors